# What to use instead of em-dash (U+2014), etc

Tags: punctuation, ambiguity

em-dash: — (U+2014) looks a lot like 一 (U+4E00) in many fonts.  What is typically used instead in Chinese print?  Or do they just rely on context?

What other punctuation alternatives should I learn?

Comment: https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-cn/%E8%BF%9E%E6%8E%A5%E5%8F%B7

Comment: Unfortunately, that article first talks about the _hyphen_, then later under em-dash, instead of telling what to use in Chinese, it tells what to use in English and gives English examples.

Comment: What do you want to use the symbol for?

Comment: For what it is supposed to be used for.  Similar to parentheses.  Or to indicate an interruption, as the Wikipedia article described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess by "in print", you mean in (normal) computers, as you also mentioned Unicode code point.

We use [破折号](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%A0%B4%E6%8A%98%E5%8F%B7) for this. And in computers, it is not one Unicode character, but **two**.

The symbol used is still U+2014, as I tested with my IME in Word. Two consecutive U+2014 form one 破折号 in Chinese. When Chinese fonts are applied, there usually no gap between the two U+2014 symbols, and it is two times longer than a normal character. (However, you might see a gap in between if non-Chinese fonts are used).

When Chinese fonts are used: To distinguish with 一 (one, U+4E00), double U+2014 is two times longer. And there is almost always a gap between two U+4E00 characters.

It might be a different story if specialized printing systems (computers), character sets, fonts, ... are used.

Comment: Well, I don't know what makes a computer "normal" but on mine, I can easily generate _any_ character in Unicode.  čŻŁą没有©§≈‰  On Windows, it can also be done, though some aren't as easy.  I checked that link, though, and I agree it's the answer.  Although it says to use U+2500 rather than U+2014.  But the two are nearly the same in appearance.  Here are two U+2500 followed by two U+2014:  ── ——

Comment: Thanks!  BTW, here shows the gap you mentioned with U+4E00: 
一一  (hard to see in a small font).

Comment: I didn't see the web page recommend U+2500, and U+2500 is for box drawing, not a punctuation.

Comment: I think you are right.  Must have been a mistake in the English translation.

Comment: But I don't know how to revert my edit.

Comment: I reverted it back.

Answer (score 0):

[中华人民共和国国家标准 标点符号用法](http://www.moe.gov.cn/ewebeditor/uploadfile/2015/01/13/20150113091548267.pdf) PRC standard of general rules for punctuation.

You can go to section 4.13 to see the examples.

```
3.13 连接号
3.13.1 连接号的形式为“－”，占一个字的位置，连接号还有另外三种形式，即长横“__”（占两个字的位置）、半字线“-”（占半个字的位置）、和浪纹“～”（占一个字的位置）。
3.13.2 两个相关的名词构成一个意义单位，中间用连接号。例如：
a) 我国秦岭－淮河以北地区属于温带季风气候区，夏季高温多雨，冬季寒冷干燥。
b) 复方氯化钠注射液，也称任－洛二氏溶液（Ringer-Locke solution），用于医疗和哺乳动物生理学实验。
3.13.3 相关的时间、地点或数目之间用连接号表示起止。例如：
a) 鲁迅（1881－1936）中国现代伟大的文学家、思想家和革命家。原名周树人，字豫才，浙江绍兴人。
b) “北京－广州”直达快车
c)梨园乡种植的巨峰葡萄已进入了丰产期，亩产1000公斤～1500公斤。
3.13.4 相关的字母、阿拉伯数字等之间，用连接号，表示产品型号。例如：
在太平洋地区，除了已建成投入使用的HAW－4和TPC－3海底光缆之外，又有TPC－4海底光缆投入运营。
3.13.5 几个相关的项目表示递进式发展，中间用连接号。例如：
人类的发展可以分为古猿－猿人－古人－新人这四个阶段。
```

破折号:

```
3.10 破折号
3.10.1 破折号的形式为“——”。
3.10.2 行文中解释说明的语句，用破折号标明。例如：
a) 迈进金黄色的大门，穿过宽阔的风门厅和衣帽厅，就到了大会堂建筑的枢纽部分——中央大厅。
b) 为了全国人民——当然包括自己在内——的幸福，我们每个人都要兢兢业业，努力工作。
3.10.3 话题突然转变，用破折号标明。例如：
“今天好热啊！——你什么时候去上海？”张强对刚刚进门的小王说。
3.10.4 声音延长，象声词后用破折号。例如：
“呜——”火车开动了。
3.10.5 事项列举分承，各项之前用破折号。例如：
根据研究对象的不同，环境物理学分为以下五个分支学科：
——环境声学；
——环境光学；
——环境热学；
——环境电磁学；
——环境空气动力学。
```

Comment: Since I am still a beginner, that doesn't help.  And since it is an image instead of text, I can't even ask Google Translate to screw it up.
Still, a nice reference for when I develop the ability to read.  :-)

Comment: @伟思礼 Text version updated, both punctuations.